# Add weak reference to assigned Closure in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following closure:

```
class BISSettingController : XLFormViewController {


  class func initializeForm() -> XLFormDescriptor {
    var form : XLFormDescriptor
    var section : XLFormSectionDescriptor
    var row : XLFormRowDescriptor


    form = XLFormDescriptor()
    row = XLFormRowDescriptor(tag: "tag", rowType: XLFormRowDescriptorTypeButton, title: "Title")
    row.action.formBlock = {[weak self](sender: XLFormRowDescriptor!) -> Void in
         self?.deselectFormRow(sender)
    ...
    }
  }

}
```

I want to use `self` as weak reference inside the closure. But when I build the code I get the following error:

```
'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type 'BISSettingController.Type'
```

**How can I solve this to make it work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this is a class method (`class func`). In a class method, `self` means *the class*. There is no need for memory management on a `self` representing the class; the class cannot "leak", because it persists for the life of the app anyway. Thus, you cannot describe a reference to a class as `weak`.

Comment: You _probably_ meant for this to be an instance method. If so, just delete that word `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you're getting, it sounds like self is not an object, so you don't need the access list at all.

Can you post more information on the object that contains this code?

### EDIT:

Looking at your updated question, it seems that the code you're using is in a class method, not an instance method. That code doesn't seem to make sense from a a class method however.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. I'm still getting used to the Swift world where enums and structs are also objects.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the problem is that the code is in a class method, not an instance method, so we were both wrong.